# Include panel in view?

Tags: views, panels

I have a view that is shown in the footer of a theme (Lucid & Nodestream Features?). Since my task and scope is small, I do not what to change up everything - just use what is there. I want to show panelized node or a panel page in the header and footer of the footer view. I have tried "Entity: Rendered entity", but I just get the node's fields and not the panel layout & content.

How do I include a panel (3.3) in a view (3.7)? (not view in a panel)

Comment: how about using [display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) which integrates panel layouts and manage display of that particular entity ?

Comment: the constraints (and some confusion) come from being stuck with someone else's site. Im not ready to ad DS to the mess :)

Answer (score 1):

The views were supposed to be displayed in the panels not viceversa. Why not created a panel with header and footer for placing views instead?

Comment: Well, that might be why im not figuring it out :D The view display is a content pane that I think is hard-coded in the theme's footer or controlled by a Feature? Im working on a site that displays the view in the footer area. Blocks are not used and Im not sure on the details. Rather than restructuring it all, I just wanted to slip a panel into the view's header.

Comment: ill accept this as the answer if there is a reference at d.o that says panels can not be in a a view.

Answer (score 0):

Though you should load view in panel and loading a panel from theme is not at all good option Still you could try something like this : http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!panels!panels.module/function/panels_load_display/7

Answer (score 0):

One can easily include mini-panels in a view but I can not find anything on displaying a panel layout in a view header. The settings suggest that one can do as much. But I also finally realized that the footer view was not coded in the theme but was content of a site template page. For now the question does not need answered.